# Do the conventional round ovens have any advantage over an OTG?

Tags: baking, equipment, oven

The "conventional round oven" *(can be used for baking, grilling and roasting, as per the claims on the packaging)* I'm referring to:
[image]

The typical Oven Toaster Griller (OTG) I'm referring to:
[image]

My objective is to buy an oven with which I can bake:

- Bread
- Cakes
- Biscuit
- Samosa (for baking it internally after frying externally)
- Puffs ([vegetable pattie](https://www.alamy.com/vegetable-pattie-is-an-indian-snack-and-is-a-mixture-of-mashed-potato-image62845120.html?pv=1&stamp=2&imageid=CD0A577C-7D20-4849-9E20-FA6A26865DA2&p=75324&n=3&orientation=0&pn=1&searchtype=0&IsFromSearch=1&srch=foo%3Dbar%26st%3D0%26sortby%3D2%26qt%3Dvegetable%2520puffs%26qt_raw%3Dvegetable%2520puffs%26qn%3D%26lic%3D3%26edrf%3D0%26mr%3D0%26pr%3D0%26aoa%3D1%26creative%3D%26videos%3D%26nu%3D%26ccc%3D%26bespoke%3D%26apalib%3D%26ag%3D0%26hc%3D0%26et%3D0x000000000000000000000%26vp%3D0%26loc%3D0%26ot%3D0%26imgt%3D0%26dtfr%3D%26dtto%3D%26size%3D0xFF%26blackwhite%3D%26cutout%3D%26archive%3D1%26name%3D%26groupid%3D%26pseudoid%3D%26userid%3D%26id%3D%26a%3D%26xstx%3D0%26cbstore%3D1%26resultview%3DsortbyPopular%26lightbox%3D%26gname%3D%26gtype%3D%26apalic%3D%26tbar%3D1%26pc%3D%26simid%3D%26cap%3D1%26customgeoip%3D%26vd%3D0%26cid%3D%26pe%3D%26so%3D%26lb%3D%26pl%3D0%26plno%3D%26fi%3D0%26langcode%3Den%26upl%3D0%26cufr%3D%26cuto%3D%26howler%3D%26cvrem%3D0%26cvtype%3D0%26cvloc%3D0%26cl%3D0%26upfr%3D%26upto%3D%26primcat%3D%26seccat%3D%26cvcategory%3D*%26restriction%3D%26collectiontype%3D%26random%3D%26ispremium%3D1%26flip%3D0%26contributorqt%3D%26plgalleryno%3D%26plpublic%3D0%26viewaspublic%3D0%26isplcurate%3D0%26imageurl%3D%26saveQry%3D%26editorial%3D1%26t%3D0%26filters%3D0))
- Chicken

I have a vague memory of someone mentioning that the conventional round oven can bake cakes more uniformly than an OTG. Additionally, some OTG's have a temperature dial like this:
[image]
This makes it really hard to figure out if I'm baking at the right temperature. Even a 10 degree temperature variation matters.

Apart from price, is there any other reason the conventional oven should be preferred?

Comment: My mom's conventional oven lasted four decades. Now it's regulator isn't working and I dont know where to get it replaced. So I'm considering either buying a conventional one or an OTG. But I need to know what the right choice is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cons of the conventional oven:**

- From what I read on [this website](https://www.cookingandme.com/2010/01/29/meet-my-oven-cheap-basic-oven-from/?unapproved=70722&moderation-hash=2ac644f68481dd1513aefa5ad286f618#comment-70722), and some Youtube videos, the
  conventional round ovens are manufactured by local brands, some of
  which may be imitation brands. For example, there's one with "Tosiba"
  written on it.
- The conventional ovens do not have a timer.
- In some ovens, the heating coil gets rusted or spoilt in a year. In
  some, the coil lasts for many decades. However, in today's times, if
  the coil gets spoilt, it's hard to find a replacement (though I do believe local electric appliance repair shops can fix it).
- The temperature setting may not be accurate.
- The thermostat is of a cheap quality, and can come off or stop
  working, and it's hard to get a replacement now.
- There's no rotisserie and no props to be able to bake items one on
  top of the other.
- OTG's have the option to heat from various directions and also have a
  fan. Conventional ovens don't.

**Pros of the conventional oven:**

- If you buy from a reputed brand (which were available many decades ago), you'll get one that cooks uniformly.
- You can easily bake a 1kg cake in it, whereas in the smaller OTG's
  you have to settle for smaller cakes.
- You can view what is being baked, directly from above, so it's easier
  to spot if it's getting burnt or not.
- The oven is less than half the price of the OTG's.